# java array searching method

Tags: java, arrays, overloading

I have to make an array whose 10 numbers are chosen by the user through a scanner. The program orders the 10 numbers in ascending order, then prints out the new list. Then It asks the user to enter any number and then uses a binary search to see if the number is in the list of 10 numbers.

### Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab11 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        double[] numbers = new double[10];        
        System.out.println("Please enter 10 double values:");
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
            numbers[i] = inputArray();
        }
        System.out.println("sorting");
        print(selectionSort(numbers));

        System.out.println("Please enter a search key:");

    }
    public static double inputArray(){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(">");
        double d = input.nextInt();
        return d;
    }

    public static double[] selectionSort(double[] list){
        double temp;
        for(int i=0; i < (list.length-1); i++){
            for(int j = i+1; j < list.length; j++){
                if(list[j] < list[i]){
                    temp = list[i];
                    list[i] = list[j];
                    list[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
    public static void print(double[] arr){
        for(double d:arr){

            System.out.println("list["+j+"]"+" = "+d);

        }

    }
    public static int binarySearch(double[]list, double key){

        int low=0,high=list.length -1;

        key =input.nextInt();

        while(high>=low){
            int mid=(low+high)/2;
            if(key<list[mid])
                    high=mid-1;
            else if(key==list[mid]) return mid;
            else low=mid+1;
        }
        return-1;
        }

    }
```

I need help with 2 things.

(1) is under the Print method. I want the program to print out like "list[i] = d" The d a number that the user puts in and it works fine, but the i doesn't. I want it to be the array number which is 0 through 9.

(2) I need help with invoking the binary search so I can have an output for the search.

Comment: why do you use `double d = input.nextInt();` instead of `double d = input.nextDouble();`?

Comment: i didn't mean to do that ,Thanks

Comment: Can you help me with the binary search method? How do I invoke the method?

Comment: I suggest moving the `double key = input.nextDouble()` into the main method (you need `final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` beforehand, of course) and invoking either your method or the binarySearch method in Mark Lee's answer via `int position = binarySearch(numbers, key)`. How to interpret the value in `position` should be clear to you.

Comment: I made all of the changes and I allows me to put a search key in but I doesnt have an output, because I  don't have one. Like this search key is not in the array. Where would I put the System.out.print(......). Do I put it in the main method or the binary search?

Comment: Yes it does have an 'output' via the return value. Make sure you understand the return value by studying the documentation for Arrays.binarySearch. The System.out.print(...) should go in your main method.

Comment: So I just put it there with like an if statement?

Answer (score 0):

I would write like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // initialize
    double[] numbers = new double[10];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // insert variables into array
    inputArray(numbers, input);

    // start sorting
    System.out.println("sorting");
    selectionSort(numbers);

    // print the sorted array
    print(numbers);

    // binary search
    binarySearch(numbers, input);

    // close scanner
    input.close();
}

public static void inputArray(double[] numbers, Scanner input) {
    System.out.println("Please enter 10 double values:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print(">");
        numbers[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }
}

public static void print(double[] numbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("list[" + i + "]" + " = " + numbers[i]);
    }
}

public static double[] selectionSort(double[] list) {
    double temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < (list.length - 1); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++) {
            if (list[j] < list[i]) {
                temp = list[i];
                list[i] = list[j];
                list[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}

public static void binarySearch(double[] numbers, Scanner input) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a search key:");
    double key = input.nextDouble();
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(numbers, key);
    if (index < 0) {
        System.out.println(key + " is not in the list");
    } else {
        System.out.println(key + " is in the list, index = " + index);
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied the code and tried it. Its still off. So say I put in the numbers: 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1. Then it sorts them to:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. That work fine. Then it asks to please enter a search key and I put in 45. It is supposed to say 45 is not in the list. Instead it wrote -11. how do I get it to say that?

Comment: I have to keep the inputArray method, it is part of the assignment. I thank you so much for helping. Can you arrange it to where I can still keep the method inputArray. I have to keep all of the methods that are in there.

Comment: Edited it. I don't think it's a good idea to post your assignment here.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the right input, you can write a do...while loop, which loops till the input is valid:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        double number;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.print(">");
            number = input.nextDouble();
        } while (number < 0 || number > 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the output you seem to want use

```
// [...] perform the sorting [...]

// enter the search key
System.out.println("Please enter a search key:");
final int position = Arrays.binarySearch(numbers, input.nextDouble());
if (position < 0) {
    System.out.println("key is not in the list");
} else {
    System.out.println("key is at position " + position);
}
```

Comment: where would I put that, could you write the whole thing out. I am sorry, I understand the whole concept of over loading and each method, but am just completely confused when putting it together.